# Saving view state android while app restarted

Tags: java, android

I am currently new to android and am working on a note taker application so please be patient with me. Inside the menu, i implemented an option whereby the user can change view if desired (List or Grid).

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null);
        mListViewSelect = (LinearLayout) customTitleView.findViewById(R.id.list_select);
        mGridViewSelect = (LinearLayout) customTitleView.findViewById(R.id.grid_select);
case R.id.changeView:
                final AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                alertbox.setView(customTitleView);
                alertbox.show();
                mListViewSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mListNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        alertbox.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        mGridViewSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        alertbox.dismiss();
    }
});
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This works perfectly. However, i want the app to open in the selected view initially selected by user. For example, if the user had closed the app while in gridview, the app should open in gridview while restarted.

I understand i need to save data persistently with shared preferences or something. But i need to know exactly what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save your data in Shared Preference, here is a way to do it.

First you need to create an instance of SharedPreferences and SharedPreferences.Editor:

```
private SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("*Desired preferences file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

> *Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor
>   (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).

```
 private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

If you need to save a String:

```
 editor.putString(key, val).commit()
```

Don't forget to do the **.commit();**

To get The String from SharedPreferences:

```
String str = settings.getString(key, "");
```

Saving Int:

just use:

`editor.putInt(key, val).commit();`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to persist data, you have options though. You say it is a note taking app, where are you saving your notes?

You could store your application's state in share preferences, described in the the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). You could store the applications state, as well as all the notes in a database, such as a relational database, of which there a tons of tutorials on and the main docs can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), or alternatively a database such as [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/), which saves objects to the database.

I would research into these options, and implement one. Then, on application launch, check the 'application state' that you have saved and adjust the UI accordingly!

Comment: thanks @calcoa. i am saving my notes in the user's device storage. so am thinking using shared preferences would be the best option for me. how about that?

Comment: Saving in shared preferences is fine for what you are doing, Fridman below has shown a good example. I would make use of the Activity lifecycle methods, saving the application state to shared preferences in onPause(). This way you will always be sure that you save the last used state.